# Fazer select dentro de um setInterval e preencher um array no nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

Estou fazendo uma aplicação que precisa ficar verificando no banco se houve alguma alteração usando o nodejs. A aplicação funciona, porém, quando eu tenho mais de um registro na tabela, ele fica duplicando os dados que guardo em um array. Por exemplo: Tenho 2 registros na tabela, no primeiro loop do setInterval, no console.log() ele me Mostra Array[2], no segundo loop, Array[4] e assim por diante.
Alguém sabe uma forma de se construir um array de dados dentro do setInterval que nao fique duplicando?
Meu código está assim:

```
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = SocketIO.listen(server);

var Agenda = {};
var horarios = [];

setInterval(function(){

var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM agenda WHERE id = 32');
query
.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
})
.on('result', function(ag) {
    Agenda = ag;
})
.on('end', function() {
})

var query2 = connection.query('SELECT * FROM horarios WHERE id_agenda = 32 ');
query2
.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
})
.on('result', function(hr) {        
    horarios.push(hr);
})
.on('end', function() { 
})    
Agenda.horario = horarios;
//console.log(JSON.stringify(Agenda));
if(horarios.length > 0){
    io.sockets.emit('time', {time: JSON.stringify(Agenda)});
}    

},3000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problema resolvido, apenas zerei o Horarios = [] depois de passar para o socket.io